# could not see Mask on Grid View panel

Tags: extjs

I am using tree grid view , Initially I am render data using memory store and after that I am changing to rest but in this scenario I could not see Mask on grid.

Comment: give `autoload:true` to grid instead of store

Answer (score 0):

Have you given loadmask config for the grid.Please share your code on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these function for masking and unmasking.

```
Ext.getBody().mask();
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```